# SIlverstripe Image DIsplay using $ThemeDir

Tags: silverstripe

When I use the content editor to edit html to display an image nothing is shown?  Below is the markup.

```
<p><img style="width: 304px; height: 228px;" title="" src="$ThemeDir/images/image1.jpg" alt="image1" /></p>
```

Comment: What value is output for $ThemeDir in the resulting page HTML?

Comment: Seems like $ThemeDir can only be used in templates, not in the HTMLEditor. You cannot put any variables in there by default. How about putting the image in assets (files and images section) and include from there?

Answer (score -1):

use themes/theme-name/images/image1.jpg instead

Answer (score -1):

$ThemeDir is removed from SilverStripe 4.0 so used src="themes/theme-name/images/3.png"